# Creating ARFF file from CSV manually

Tags: csv, weka, arff

I wanted to create an [`arff`](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) file based on this `CSV` from `Kaggle`

https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv

here is a part of the `arff` file I've made

```
@relation titanic

@attribute PassengerId numeric
@attribute Survived {0,1}
@attribute Pclass {1,2,3}
@attribute Name string
@attribute Sex {male,female}
@attribute Age numeric
@attribute SibSp numeric
@attribute Parch numeric
@attribute Ticket string
@attribute Fare numeric
@attribute Cabin string
@attribute Embarked {C,Q,S}

@data
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
```

But whene I load it in [`Weka`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/) it returns me this error :

```
nominal value not declared in header, read Token[C85], line 18 % the second line of my data
```

what is wrong in my declarations ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a comma inside the name `"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)"`. Weka parses this as two fields in spite of double quotes.

You can try to remove such commas (that is, commas within double quotes) with the help of regular expression.